# Why can't I post a comment anymore?

Tags: support, comments

Is anyone else getting this or is it just me?

I seem to be able to ask questions, or at least the option is there and it brings up the dialog box.  I have not gone all the way to posting a question to avoid confusion  (well apart from this one, obviously).

I know that users can be prevented from asking questions if they get too many down votes (or something) but I have not seen anything similar for comments?

When I click on Add Comment the box appears as normal.  I fill it in and then press Add Comment.  The screen refreshes with the focus now at the top of the screen.  I scroll down to where my comment should be and it is not there.

The OS is Windows Server and I am using Internet Explorer 10.  However, I was able to post comments yesterday and I have not intentionally changed anything since then.

It still happens when I disable all add ons - it looks like it is the same situation across all of the stack overflow sites for me.  When I try via my IPhone nothing happens after I type the comment and press "Add Comment".

Have I been prevented from posting comments?

---

### Q & A

> What OS/browser?

The OS is Windows Server and I am using Internet Explorer 10.  I have also tried from my IPhone and that does not work either.

> Does it still happen if you run IE with all add-ons disabled?

Yes

> Have you cleared the cache and closed all instances?

Not sure what clearing the cache means?
I have restarted IE on my PC and Safari on my phone.

> Also, make sure that *.scifi.stackexchange.com is in the Internet Zone and not Restricted (Internet Options -> Security)

I have confirmed that *.scifi.stackexchange.com is not in the restricted zone.

> Have you tried it from another browser/device? That would help confirm if it's something to do with your account.

From my PC and IPhone.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: What OS/browser? It's possible that it's a css/js bug.

Comment: Does it still happen if you run IE with all add-ons disabled?

Comment: Posting this from an iPhone.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache and closed all instances?

Comment: Also, make sure that `*.scifi.stackexchange.com` is in the Internet Zone and not Restricted (Internet Options -> Security)

Comment: Have you tried it from another browser/device? That would help confirm if it's something to do with your account.

Comment: I added these questions to the question body. Stefan, as you try each one add answers.

Comment: Fixed it, I will post the answer below in case someone else gets the same issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I had *compatibility view* checked in the tools menu.  I have unchecked it and can now post comments.

Curiously I can also post comments from my IPhone now.  I am not sure why that would be the case?  Perhaps the CV left something in a zombie state somehow?